# Include? condition in haml view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I try to make something like this in haml view :

```
%li{:class => @taxon and ([@taxon] + @taxon.ancestors).include?(taxon) : "current"}
```

what the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the value of @taxon is the class name? If so this should work for you.

```
- taxon_class = (@taxon && ([@taxon] + @taxon.ancestors).include?(taxon)) ? @taxon : "current"
%li{:class => taxon_class}
```

I always find it easier to do the ruby logic outside of the haml {} brackets.